# Powershell ExportCSV exports an empty file when the imported file comes from Import-csv

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a CSV file where I need to change the delimiter from comma to semicolon.
I fixed this issue with following command

```
(Import-CSV $File) | Export-Csv $File -delimiter ';' -notypeinformation
```

But when the imported CSV file contains only one line which I assume is being handled as the headers. It deletes this line in the output file and it becomes an empty file.
However when I have more than one line and the csv contains the header and some data the exported file is being executed correctly with the headers and the data.

Code that I used to set the header file in the beginning of my script

```
#set csv headers
Set-Content -Path "$FolderNameCiTypeDelta" -Value "name,type,location,size"
```

I've tried adding the code

```
  (Import-CSV $File -Header "name,type,location,size") | Export-Csv $File -delimiter ';' -notypeinformation
```

But this made just an extra line with the headers I specified.

[EDIT]

The 2 csv files that I test with contain the following lines

The file that becomes empty with the import --> export command contains

```
name,type,location,size
```

The file that performs what I need with the import --> export command contains

```
name,type,location,size
test,extra,line
```

Comment: please add a sanitized sample of the file that is failing to work as expected.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I've added the sample of the csv file that I use as an input

Comment: thank you for the added info! [*grin*] it looks like `AdminOfThings` has posted a working solution to your problem ... so i will go back to lurking.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
$file = 't.txt'
$contents = Get-Content $file -totalcount 2
if ($contents.Count -gt 1) {
    (Import-Csv $file) | Export-Csv $file -Delimiter ';' -NoType
}
if ($contents.Count -eq 1) {
    $contents -replace ',',';' | Set-Content $file
}
```

The idea here is to read two lines of your file. If it only contains one line, it will use `-replace` to fix your delimiters. If it has more than two lines, it will use the `*-Csv` commands.

The `-replace` section only works if you don't have commas in your field values. If you do have commas in your fields, then you should have text qualifiers (double quotes most likely) around your fields. In that case, you can simply use `-replace '","','";"'`.